# How to save several images at the same time in firebase using the photo camera with ionic and angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

How can I save multiple images to storage? This code, what is done is, the camera is used, when you take the photo an image arrangement is created and clicking upload only uploads one image to firestorage, but I don't know how to upload multiple images, any ideas?

Complete and detailed code:

```
public imagesArray: Array<any> = new Array<any>();
captureDataUrl: string;
alertCtrl: AlertController;
```

```typescript
capture() {
  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  };

  this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
    imageData => {
      // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
      // If it's base64:

      this.captureDataUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.imagesArray.push(this.captureDataUrl);
    },
    err => {
      // Handle error
    },
  );
} // End of capture camera

upload() {
  let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  // Create a timestamp as filename

  const filename = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  // Create a reference to 'images/todays-date.jpg'

  const imageRef = storageRef.child(`images/${filename}.jpg`);

  imageRef
    .putString(this.captureDataUrl, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL)
    .then(snapshot => {
      // Do something here when the data is succesfully uploaded!
    });
}
```

```
the html component:

<ng-container *ngFor="let i of imagesArray;">
       <img src='{{i}}' /> 
  </ng-container>

 <ion-button ion-button (click)="capture()"> take a photo!</ion-button>
 <ion-button ion-button (click)="upload()"  >upload firebase!</ion-button>
```

I want to upload two or more photos at the same time, or rather that it be multiple, what the code does is that when taking a photo it is saved in firebase, but if I take two photos only one is saved.

Comment: the problem is unclear. what exactly is the issue? do you want to upload the photo that you just did 2 times? If first photo is taken from camera than what is the source of the second one?

Comment: I want to upload two or more photos at the same time, or rather that it be multiple, what the code does is that when taking a photo it is saved in firebase, but if I take two photos only one is saved

Comment: try `Date.now();` instead of `Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);`. maybe there is a name collision

Comment: It does not work, it is that each time you click on upload, it uploads a single image

Comment: how do you take 2 photos at the same moment?

Comment: not only, I take a photo and an image array is generated with img, I want an array to be generated but it is saved to firebase -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that:

- There is an an `UPLOAD` button somewhere in the app.
- When you click it, it invokes the `upload()` method.

If that's the case, of course only a single image is uploaded. In the `capture()` method you write:

```typescript
// You save the data of the LAST captured image
this.captureDataUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
// You then push it to an array containing all images (that's good!)
this.imagesArray.push(this.captureDataUrl);
```

In `upload()` you have:

```typescript
// You pass `this.captureDataUrl`, i.e. the LAST captured image! That's not what you want!
imageRef.putString(this.captureDataUrl, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL)
```

Instead you should *iterate over* `this.imagesArray`, something like this:

```typescript
upload() {
  let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

  Promise.all(
    // Go over ALL captured images
    // UPDATE 1
    this.imagesArray.map((imageUrl, imageIndex) => {
      // Create a timestamp as filename
      // UPDATE 1
      const filename = `${Date.now()}-${imageIndex}`;

      // Create a reference to 'images/todays-date.jpg'
      const imageRef = storageRef.child(`images/${filename}.jpg`);

      // Upload that particular image and return the upload Promise
      return imageRef
        .putString(imageUrl, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL)
        .then(snapshot => {
          // Do something here when the data is succesfully uploaded!
        });
    }),
  ).then(
    () => {
      console.log('All images uploaded!');
    },
    err => {
      console.error('Some images failed to upload...', err);
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: just save an image, it is appreciated anyway

Comment: Ah, right, there might also be a filename clash. I have updated the code (updates denoted with comments `UPDATE 1`), check it out.